# Converting a Set to Dict in python

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a set like this.

```
x = set([u'[{"Mychannel":"sample text"},"p"]'])
```

I need to convert it into Dict.

I need to get output as

```
x = {'mychannel':'sampletext'}
```

How to do this.

Comment: Can you give some alternate examples of your data and expected output? This is not a straightforward set-to-dict conversion, if there even is one.

Comment: How on earth did you get a data structure like that? It's a `dict` inside a `list` inside a `string` inside a `list` inside a `set`. I think...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can unpack that crazy thing like this:

```
>>> x = set([u'[{"Mychannel":"sample text"}, "p"]'])
>>> lst = list(x)
>>> lst
[u'[{"Mychannel":"sample text"}, "p"]']
>>> lst[0]
u'[{"Mychannel":"sample text"}, "p"]'
>>> inner_lst = eval(lst[0])
>>> inner_lst
[{'Mychannel': 'sample text'}, 'p']
>>> d = inner_lst[0]
>>> d
{'Mychannel': 'sample text'}
```

However, as @MattDMo suggests in comments, I seriously suggest you re-evaluate this data structure, if not at least to factor out the step where you need `eval` to use it!

Comment: You could replace the `eval` with `ast.literal_eval`, but as you say it's probably a better idea to simplify whatever's producing this.

Comment: I suspect OP has enough control to use a better data structure somewhere else, since the first step to unpacking it seems to be reversing his call to set on it in the displayed code. That's making it more complicated instead of less (an operation which seems to have occurred a number of times here).